# Display The Percentage of a Completion of a Calculation in a Label

Tags: c#

I have write this code for calculate employee salary. It's work fine. Now I want to show the percentage value of the process completion in a label instead of adding an progress bar.

But it's not working as I want. Label text updating as "Salary Processing : 100%" only after all process completed.

I tried with the value of progPrec with breakpoint and I make sure that it's also updating. But the problem is the value of that is not showing in lblPercentage label.

(I tried with a background worker and with a timer too. but it was also failed.)

Please give me a solution

```
int progPrec=0;
int ProcessedEmployees=0;
int AllEmployees = WorkersList.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

for (int x = 0; x < AllEmployees ; x++)
{

   //Codings For Salary Processing Comes Here

   ProcessedEmployees++;      

   int progPrec = (int)Math.Round(((double)(ProcessedEmployees) / (double)(AllEmployees)) * 100);

   lblPercentage.Text = "Salary Processing : " + progPrec + " %";

}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I've tried with a background worker too. also with a timer. But I couldn't accomplish that.
If you could please give me the coding

Comment: You might want to put how you code your background worker then?